# kubernetes service account permissions

Tags: kubernetes

When I create a service account on my docker-desktop kubernetes environment on windows 10 using

```
kubectl create serviceaccount test -n test-namespace
```

if I run the following command it returns 'yes'

```
kubectl auth can-i create pods --all-namespaces --token <token from test service account>
```

but if I run the same on setup on a cloud managed kubernetes cluster it returns 'no'

What is the difference in the setups? I'm trying to limit control on a local cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution this also applies to windows https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3694#issuecomment-619474504